# HTML encode datetime using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a string of date time in utc like:

```
2020-12-24T23:30:00+00:00
```

I want this to be coverted to html encoding:

```
2020-12-24T23%3A30%3A00%2B00%3A00
```

Can it be done using urllib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`urllib.parse.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote).

```
>>> from urllib.parse import quote
>>> quote("2020-12-24T23:30:00+00:00")
'2020-12-24T23%3A30%3A00%2B00%3A00'
```

You can also use [`quote_from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_from_bytes) which is similar `quote()`, but accepts a bytes object rather than a `str`, and does not perform string-to-bytes encoding

```
>>> from urllib.parse import quote_from_bytes
>>> quote_from_bytes("2020-12-24T23:30:00+00:00".encode("utf-8"))
'2020-12-24T23%3A30%3A00%2B00%3A00'
```